# How to do that a Container follow path of Containers? (AnimatedContainer)

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a grid of Containers (blue and red containers), and on top of that, a green Container (with StackWidget) which I need move throught red Containers (path)

[image]

Is possible to achieve what I need?
I have the grid of containers and a list with path coords

```
List<Map<int, int>> path = [
  {2: 0},
  {2: 1},
  {2: 2},
  {2: 3},
  {2: 4},
  {3: 4},
  {4: 4},
  {5: 4},
  {5: 5},
  {5: 6},
  {5: 7},
  //...
```

Comment: My friend this is a really good question but arduous at the same time. I suggest you put a bounty on it or else I do not think anyone will answer

Comment: Ok, I can add bounty in 16 hours... If there is a chance to animate a widget so that it follows a path, it could also be useful for me in another way